# Does canvas have a display event handler?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am used to using GLUT's [PostRedisplay](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node20.html) and (App|UI)Kit's [setNeedsDisplay](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/setNeedsDisplay) methods for requesting a new *display event* to be posted to the event queue when the app wishes to redraw a scene. I haven't found a counterpart with HTML5's Canvas element. For example, I am currently just calling my `display()` function directly when I want to redraw to the canvas:

```
function mouseMove(event) {
      if (mouseDrag) {
          // update camera position
          display();
      }
  }
```

The `display()` function renders the scene (which can be expensive):

```
function display() {
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      // issue WebGL calls to redraw scene
      gl.flush();
}
```

Most systems I am used to will coalesce multiple display events into one event if multiple rendering requests occur before the last rendering is finished. What I am doing above can be problematic if a long stream of `display()` calls outpace the rendering speed.

Anyway, what is the correct way to redraw canvas elements effeciently?

[You can see the demo app I am working on here](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs442/lectures/rot/revolve/revolve.html) (if you have WebGL enabled).

**Update** : Following the answer below I now use  `RequestAnimationFrame` and use the return value as a flag to indicate that a request has already been made. When the scene is rendered I clear the flag so further requests can be made:

```
var requestId = 0; // id of current requestAnimationFrame request (0 = no request)

function mouseMove(event) {
      if (mouseDrag) {
          // update camera position
          if (requestId)
            requestId = requestAnimationFrame(display);
          else
             console.log("request already in queued"); // test
      }
 }

function display() {
      requestId = 0;
      // redraw scene
}
```

Noting the log messages I get this does indeed coalesce multiple requests. This seems like a great approach. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: I edited your example. it's `requestAnimationFrame`, not `requestAnimFrame`. requestAnimFrame was a polyfill but every browser that supports WebGL supports RAF so no need for the polyfill. On top of that RAF returns a request id that can be used to cancel the request with `cancelAnimationFrame`. On top of that the spec allows `requestAnimationFrame` to return `0` so you can't check for zero. You need to get check for `undefined`.

Comment: @gman "On top of that the spec allows requestAnimationFrame to return 0" No it doesn't. From http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/: "an entry whose handle is a user-agent-defined integer **greater than zero**"

Comment: Specs don't meet reality? I could swear I've gotten zero from it back in the day. Also from setTimeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `requestAnimationFrame(display)` to set a callback (in this case, `display`) to be called at the next repaint.

It's up to you to only call it once when waiting for a repaint (at the repaint, it will do the callback for *each* call you made to `requestAnimationFrame`). It's also up to you to request *another* animation frame if you want to animate continuously.

Comment: @stuart-p-bentley So if a sequence of rapid events cause their handlers to invoke `requestAnimationFrame` before a frame is redrawn, will these requests be coalesced into a single animation frame being requested? -- I guess this would be easy to test. Is this the usual practice for non-animations? -- like in my app above?

Comment: I replaced `display()` with `for(var i=0;i<100;i++)requestAnimationFrame(display);` and logged every time `display()` is invoked. Unfortunately, `display()` is indeed getting called 100 times -- so  `requestAnimationFrame()` does *not* coalesce multiple requests. Bummer.

Comment: It's not hard to coalesce them yourself, though. Just do `var frame;` outside whatever code is going to invoke requestAnimationFrame, then `if (!frame) frame=requestAnimationFrame(function display(){frame=null; /*other code goes here*/ })` inside it (display function inlined for comment brevity)

Comment: I see -- when the request is made `frame` will be assigned some integer value -- as long as `frame` is not `null` subsequent requests will not happen. (I assume these calls happen on a single thread). It seems like that would work. It would be comforting to see this described somewhere -- this must be a common issue. I hate to get to far off the beaten path.

Comment: @stuart-p-bentley This seems to do the trick -- I am updating the question using your solution.

Comment: Just for clarification it's not a bummer that RAF queues multiple callbacks. It's required. You could have 50 different unrelated scripts on your page all wanting to add a RAF callback. Maybe you've got 2 banner ads using RAF and 3 different unrelated visualizations. If RAF didn't support queuing multiple callbacks per frame all but one of those would break.